# C: Confusing types when allocating memory

Tags: c

For the following declaration of graph (that I cannot change - assignment),

```
#define TAG(vp)   ((vp)->tag)
#define LABEL(vp) ((vp)->label)  
#define EDGE(vp)  ((vp)->edge)

typedef struct vertex 
{
    char tag;
    char *label;
    struct vertex *edge[1];
}
vertex, *vp;
```

when I allocate memory with the following line

```
EDGE (test) = (vp *) malloc (sizeof (vp) * 3); // where test is a node of a graph
```

I get the following error

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct vertex *[1]’ from type ‘struct vertex **
```

Also I cannot assign EDGE as NULL. I guess I'm missing something with the declaration (it uses *ptr[1] which is quite confusing me). Can you help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169)

Comment: See http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?StructHack.

Comment: just to point out, remove `,` from `vertex, *vp;`

Comment: @SuvP: The `typedef` is defining two types, a `vertex` that is the structure representing a vertex and a`vp` that is a pointer to a `vertex`. Removing the comma would break the code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Aha! Thanks. I must be half blind to see only that single line. I assumed (for some reason) that he defined a struct typedefed as `vertex` (missed out the ; at the end) and then created a pointer. I thought its a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking at is pre-C99 code called the ["struct hack"](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html).  In C99 or later, you'd use a [flexible array member](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEMxx-C.+Understand+how+flexible+array+members+are+to+be+used).

The general idea is that you allocate the structure plus some extra space at the end that you use through the array member:

```
struct vertex *v = malloc(sizeof *v + n * sizeof(struct vertex *));
```

To allocate a structure with space for `n` edges (and a sentinel, as @EricPostpischil mentions below).  I didn't use your `*vp` typedef, since I don't like hiding pointer types via typedef like that.

After that allocation, you can just use the array like normal:

```
v->edge[0] = &someOtherVertex;
v->edge[1] = &someOtherOtherVertex;
```

And so on.

Comment: I considered this as well, but the structure does not seem to contain an indication of the number of the elements in the array, so it is not clear. It might be possible that a sentinel is intended, likely a null pointer. (In which case, one would allocate space for `n` additional elements, not `n-1`.) And an answer should also explain more of the code that is necessary to achieve the desired allocation and use of the structure.

Comment: I added some of that, and the C FAQ link has plenty of explanation I think.  You're probably right about the sentinel.

Comment: i'm bit confused about why you have added "sizeof *v" when allocating

Comment: That's the allocation space required for the structure itself.  It could as easily be `sizeof(struct vertex)`.  `sizeof` is an operator - it works on variables as well as on types.

Comment: since i cannot assign "edge" to NULL, how do i declare a node that has no edges? i mean how can i make "edge" empty?

Comment: `EDGE(v)[0] = NULL`, I guess?

Comment: by the way, i use these "hiding pointer types" since in this assignment it is not allowed to use "." and "->" operators

Answer (score 2):

If you want just one edge per vertex do:

```
struct vertex *edge;
```

Or else you can modify your macros (ug? why?) such as:

```
#define EDGE(vp)  ((vp)->edge[0])
```

but you probably want the first option, as you seem to be creating the array dynamically.

What you cannot do is to assign to the array itself: either make it a pointer or assign to the (only) element of the array.

Note that the usual idiom in C to create a dynamic array is declaring a plain pointer and make it point to the first element of the dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

Using the readily available on linux systems program, `cdecl` I can see what does

```
 struct vertex *edge[1];
```

mean:

```
adi@laps:~$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain struct vertex *edge[1];
declare edge as array 1 of pointer to struct vertex
cdecl>
```

Thus your prescribed data structure represents the edges coming out of a vertex as pointers stored in a structure. Because you do not have any count of how many edges there are, you are left to use a sentinel, NULL, to mark the end of the array.

Thus `EDGE(vp)[0]` is the first coincident vertex, `EDGE(vp)[1]` is the second, etc., until you read a NULL.

This is called the *trailing array idiom* and you must remember that `sizeof(struct vertex)` is the amount of memory needed for a vertex having no edges (only the sentinel) and whenever adding more edges to a vertex, you must make sure that enough memory was allocated for the block holding the struct.

Also, this idiom has been standarized in C99 as the flexible arrays and the difference is you do not declare the size of the array

```
 struct vertex {
      struct vertex* edge[];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
EDGE (test) = (vp *) malloc (sizeof (vp) * 3);
```

you need to do

```
EDGE (test) = malloc (sizeof (vp)); // to allocate array of pointer to vertex
EDGE (test)[0] = malloc (sizeof (vertex)); // to allocate the vertex itself.
```

if you cannot change

```
struct vertex *edge[1];
```